# WPF Value comes empty in ValueConverter

Tags: wpf, mvvm, ivalueconverter

I have a WPF app to display some LogMessage list. The LogMessage class looks like this:

```
public class LogMessage
{
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
    public LogLevel LogLevel { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

I want to bind the value of `LogLevel` to `Foreground` property of a `TextBlock` using this ValueConverter:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(LogLevel), typeof(Brush))]
public class LogLevelToColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var logLevel = (LogLevel)value;
        switch (logLevel)
        {
            case LogLevel.Info:
                return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.DarkGray);
            case LogLevel.Important:
                return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
            case LogLevel.Warning:
                return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Orange);
            case LogLevel.Error:
                return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
            default:
                return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.DarkGray);
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

The view looks likke this:

```
<Window x:Class="TouchLogic.EcrServer.Wpf.Views.MainView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TouchLogic.EcrServer.Wpf.ViewModels"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainView" Height="450" Width="800">

    <Window.Resources>
        <local:LogLevelToColorConverter x:Key="LogLevelToColorConverter"/>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid Margin="8">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="140" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <ListBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding LogMessages}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Timestamp}" Foreground="{Binding LogLevel, Converter={StaticResource LogLevelToColorConverter}}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Message}" Foreground="{Binding LogLevel, Converter={StaticResource LogLevelToColorConverter}}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

My problem is that `value` in my value converter always comes as `0`, and I don't know why.

Comment: Your code looks ok. Are you sure that there actually is a LogMessage with LogLevel != 0 ? As a note, instead of `new SolidColorBrush(Colors.DarkGray)` you could as well use `Brushes.DarkGray`. There is a Brush in Brushes for every Color in Colors.

Comment: Yes, I initialize the list in the contructor with `LogMessages = new BindableCollection<LogMessage> { new LogMessage(LogLevel.Info, "Info Message"),`.

Comment: And LogLevel.Info is not zero? Is LogLevel an enum type? What does it exactly mean when you say "*comes as 0*"? Does `var logLevel = (LogLevel)value;` not work?

Comment: LogLevel is an enum where LogLevel.Info equals 10. `value` comes in the converter as 0.

Comment: And the LogMessage constructor (that you haven't shown us) really sets the LogLevel property?

Comment: Stupid me :) .... sory I have wasted your time. It was wrongly typed like this: `this.LogLevel = LogLevel;` instead of `this.LogLevel = level`. I appologise again for not paying more attention.